# how to call sgemm in a custom TensorFlow C++ op

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm following the [tutorial on how to define my own op for TensorFlow in C++](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/adding_an_op/).

I want to call `sgemm` in my custom TensorFlow C++ op. I am writing two kernels, one for CUDA and one for CPU. How would the `sgemm` call in each case look like? Or is there a generic method which works for both cases?

I tried with this code snippet but I cannot get it to work because of missing include files (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6602)):

```
auto dev_ctx = context->op_device_context();
auto* dev_stream = dev_ctx->stream();
OP_REQUIRES(context, dev_stream, errors::Internal("No stream available."));

bool blas_launch_status =
    dev_stream
         ->ThenBlasGemm(...
```

Also, not sure if this is generic or if this would be for CUDA only.

Is this anywhere documented?

How can I call `cublasSgemm` in my GPU/CUDA implementation?
Or more precisely, how to get the `cublasHandle_t`?

I searched a bit through the TF code and there is the [class `CUDABlas`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.h) which seems to provide wrappers around the cuBLAS functions. Do I need to use this or can I use `cublasSgemm` directly?
I guess I need to use the wrapper as this will make sure that the CUDA stream executer stays in a sane state? How do I use the wrapper?

I also found [contrib/rnn/kernels/blas_gemm.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/blas_gemm.cc) and [core/kernels/matmul_op.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.cc) which seems to do what I want. The code looks like this:

```
#define EIGEN_USE_THREADS

#if GOOGLE_CUDA
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/stream_executor.h"
#endif  // GOOGLE_CUDA

#include "tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/blas_gemm.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
namespace tensorflow {

#if GOOGLE_CUDA
namespace {
template <typename T>
perftools::gputools::DeviceMemory<T> AsDeviceMemory(const T* cuda_memory) {
  perftools::gputools::DeviceMemoryBase wrapped(const_cast<T*>(cuda_memory));
  perftools::gputools::DeviceMemory<T> typed(wrapped);
  return typed;
}
}  // namespace
#endif  // GOOGLE_CUDA

namespace functor {
template <typename T>
void TensorCuBlasGemm<T>::operator()(OpKernelContext* ctx,
                                     bool transa, bool transb, uint64 m,
                                     uint64 n, uint64 k, T alpha, const T* a,
                                     int lda, const T* b, int ldb, T beta, T* c,
                                     int ldc) {
#if GOOGLE_CUDA
  perftools::gputools::blas::Transpose trans[] = {
      perftools::gputools::blas::Transpose::kNoTranspose,
      perftools::gputools::blas::Transpose::kTranspose};

  auto a_ptr = AsDeviceMemory(a);
  auto b_ptr = AsDeviceMemory(b);
  auto c_ptr = AsDeviceMemory(c);

  bool blas_launch_status =
      ctx->op_device_context()
          ->stream()
          ->ThenBlasGemm(trans[transa], trans[transb], m, n, k, alpha, a_ptr,
                         lda, b_ptr, ldb, beta, &c_ptr, ldc)
          .ok();
  OP_REQUIRES(ctx, blas_launch_status, errors::Aborted("CuBlasGemm failed!"));
#else
  ctx->SetStatus(errors::InvalidArgument("CuBlasGemm needs CUDA."));
#endif
}
```

I.e. in my `Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx)`, I would call

```
ctx->op_device_context()
      ->stream()
      ->ThenBlasGemm(...)
```

I tried that but it seems that some include headers are missing for me (TensorFlow 0.12.0 with GPU for Linux). I get `fatal error: tensorflow/stream_executor/lib/status.h: No such file or directory`. I reported that upstream [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6602).

Is there any documentation about all this, i.e. how to handle cuBLAS, or this `DeviceStream` interface, the stream executer logic, etc?

My current solution was kind of hacky. For CPU, I try to link against some available Blas library on the system and use `sgemm` from there. For CUDA, I link to `tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/_lstm_ops.so` because in there I have found `TensorCuBlasGemm`which I can use. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/blas_gemm.cc). Basically, in that contrib op, they face the same issue and have come up with [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/blas_gemm.h). But that partly depends on include files which are not available in general, see the issue above.

Comment: Are you asking about using CUBLAS within a CUDA kernel you are going to write, or just calling CUBLAS from within a host side operator?

Comment: @talonmies: Would that make a difference? I would be interested in both cases. In my case, I write my own GPU operation which should call some own CUDA kernel as well as `cublasSgemm`.

Comment: Yes, it makes a big difference. And two different questions. One related to CUDA, the other to tensorflow. Choose one would be my suggestion.

Comment: @talonmies: I extended my question.

Comment: OK so this really isn't a CUDA programming question, much more about TF internals

Comment: @Albert Did you figure out how to use streams in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following which worked for me today:
In your *.cu.cc file at the beginning:

```
#include <cublas_v2.h>
cublasHandle_t cublas_handle = NULL;
```

In the same *.cu.cc file in the **functor** implementation:

```
if (cublas_handle == NULL)
{
    assert(cublasCreate(&cublas_handle) == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS);
    assert(cublasSetStream(cublas_handle, d.stream()) == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS);
}
```

where the `d` is passed into the functor from the *.cc file as a parameter whose value is `ctx->eigen_device<Eigen::GpuDevice>()`

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: If `dev_ctx->stream()` works now, then the whole hack about using a custom cublas handle is not needed anymore, right? So then my first code snippet should already work.